# How do I parallelize my interfaces in gradio in the new version?

Tags: python, gradio

I have the following code:

```
int1= gr.Interface(fn=fn1,
          inputs='image',
          outputs=gr.Label(num_top_classes=3),
          live=False)
int2 = gr.Interface(fn=fn2,
          inputs='image',
          outputs=gr.Label(num_top_classes=3),
          live=False)
int3 = gr.Interface(fn=fn3,
          inputs='image',
          outputs=gr.Label(num_top_classes=3),
          live=False)

with gr.Blocks() as all_int:
    gr.Parallel(int1, int2, int3)

all_int.launch(show_api=False,share=True)
```

But when I updated Gradio to the latest (4.7.1) `gr.Parallel` is already depreciated. How do I execute the same code in the new version? I tried using them on the same block but it gives me 3 image inputs instead of only one.